# Converting SDL F32 Bytes to samples [-1.0 - 1.0] results in static noise

Tags: c++, floating-point, sdl-2

**I'm trying to convert microphone input from an SDL2 Audio Device into floating point samples.** Currently I'm getting static - *not consistent static* - but rather static that responds to microphone input.

So when microphone is not being talked into, no audible static. When microphone is, static follows phrases and dynamic changes. I feel like I'm really close to getting it working but I'm doing something (probably obvious) wrong.

I'm setting up the audio device in SDL as follows:

```
SDL_AudioSpec as;
as.freq = aSamplerate;
as.format = AUDIO_F32;
as.channels = 1;
as.samples = aBuffer;
as.callback = _sdl_cb;
as.userdata = (void*)aSoloud;
gAudioDeviceID = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 1, &as, &gActiveAudioSpec, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_ANY_CHANGE & ~(SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_FORMAT_CHANGE | SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_CHANNELS_CHANGE));
if (gAudioDeviceID == 0)
{
    as.format = AUDIO_S16;
    gAudioDeviceID = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 1, &as, &gActiveAudioSpec, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_ANY_CHANGE & ~(SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_FORMAT_CHANGE | SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_CHANNELS_CHANGE));
    if (gAudioDeviceID == 0)
    {
        return UNKNOWN_ERROR;
    }
}

//Calculate per sample bytes
int bytesPerSample = gActiveAudioSpec.channels * ( SDL_AUDIO_BITSIZE( gActiveAudioSpec.format ) / 8 );

gBufferByteSize = bytesPerSample * aBuffer;

audioHoldingPattern = new Uint8[ gBufferByteSize ];

memset( audioHoldingPattern, 0, gBufferByteSize );
SDL_PauseAudioDevice(gAudioDeviceID, 0);
```

- gActiveAudioSpec is the returned 'proper' spec from SDL.
- audioHoldingPattern is literally a holding pattern for my audio buffers on the callback (as you'll see below). I need something like this as I'm using this with a library (SoLoud) which requests buffers, as opposed to accepts them. The latest buffer is held here until it is sent back to SoLoud.

This is what I'm doing in my SDL callback:

```
static void _sdl_cb(void * userdata, Uint8 * pcm, int len){
    if (SDL_GetAudioDeviceStatus(gAudioDeviceID) == SDL_AUDIO_PLAYING) {
        memcpy( &audioHoldingPattern[0], pcm, len );
    }
}
```

And this is where SoLoud requests new buffers from:

```
unsigned int MicrophoneInstance::getAudio(float* aBuffer, unsigned int aSamplesToRead, unsigned int aBufferSize)
{       
        int size = aBufferSize;
        float *signal = reinterpret_cast<float*>(audioHoldingPattern);

        memcpy(aBuffer, signal, aBufferSize);

        return (unsigned int)sizeof(signal);
}
```

- aBuffer is the buffer SoLoud provides to copy to

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information in your post to help you. When you set up the SDL audio context, you've specified the expected audio format (probably 16 bits, little endian, signed). It can be something like S16LE or U16LE or ...

Once you've found this in your code, you'll need to convert the buffer you're receiving to the asked format first, and then compute the value in a floating point.

For example, if the audio buffer format is S16LE (signed 16 bits little endian) and you are on a little endian machine (very likely), then you'll do something like this:

```
   Int16 sample; // Range of data is +32767 -32768 or ~ +/- 1<<15 - 1
   float scale = (float)(1.0 / (double)(1 << (sizeof(sample) - 1)));
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i += sizeof(sample)) 
   {
      memcpy(&sample, &pcm[i], sizeof(sample)); // Use this so it'll work on machine that don't allow non-aligned access to char buffers
      float s = sample * scale;
      [...] // Do whatever you want with s
   }
```

EDIT: You have an issue with your code.
First, you are requesting 32 bits float samples (line `as.format = AUDIO_F32;` and first call to `SDL_OpenAudioDevice`).
Then, if it fails, you ask for S16 (signed 16 bits) as in my example above.
The issue is that you don't track what format you'll get (is it float? is it S16?).

So, either remove the first call with a F32 format and only leave the S16 format (and use the code above to convert it).
Or, store the accepted format somewhere and act differently based on the accepted format.

In the F32 case, you can convert the `pcm` variable to a `float*` by casting it like this: `float * buffer = (float*)pcm;`